# Changing a Django model from ForeignKey to ManytoMany getting Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'group'. Choices are: user

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I want to change my post models. Before I had a very simple relation. There are 3 models `User`, `Post` and `Group`. A user can create posts and the post has to belong to 1 group.
*example:* The user Samir wrote a post on Football. This post belongs to the group Sports. Below is how the models look

**Earlier Model:**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='posts')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, unique=True, max_length=500)
    message = models.TextField()
```

I want to change this such that each post can belong to a maximum of 3 and minimum of 1 group.

**Below is my model**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')
    group = models.ManyToManyField(Group, related_name='posts', max_length=3)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, unique=True, max_length=500)
    message = models.TextField()
```

The post is created successfully but does not redirect to the post detail page and gives the below error. Also in the django admin the group in posts is blank. Below is my DetailView

**My Views are:**

```
from braces.views import SelectRelatedMixin

class PostDetail(SelectRelatedMixin, DetailView):
    model = Post
    select_related = ('user', 'group')

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(user__username__iexact=self.kwargs.get('username'))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetail, self).get_context_data()            
        return context
```

My Url for the DetailView is:

```
url(r'^(?P<username>[-\w]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='single'),
```

Below is the error
[image]

I tried changing the `select_related` to `prefetch_related` but the problem still persists. How do I fix this

*******Below based on @Ruddra's solution*****

I am sorry I believe this is almost solved. After I changed the select related I got the below error

[image]

I believe this may have something to do with my groups url, Below are my group `model`, `view` and `url` which are very simple

**Model**

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='GroupMember')
```

The view is a 1 liner

```
class GroupCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Group
    fields = ('name', 'description')


class GroupList(ListView):
    model = Group


class GroupDetail(DetailView):
    model = Group
```

And finally the **Url** is

```
url(r'^posts/in/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.GroupDetail.as_view(), name='single'),
```

What do you think I am doing wrong

Comment: after you change relation, your command `makemigrations` and `migrate` run successfully ?

Comment: yes they do. They run successfully

Comment: can you recheck real database, have any new table have group_id and post_id ?. This table will keep real data of many to many. And can you post your file of command `makemigrations` ?

Comment: Just FYI, `max_length` has no effect on `ManyToManyField`

Comment: maybe change to `PrefethRelatedMixin` with `prefetch_related='posts'` . Because you define `related_name='posts'`.

Comment: @NgocPham trying this in 2 mins

Comment: @BurhanKhalid thank you, I just figured that too. Trying to look for alternatives as soon as I resolve the bigger issue

Comment: @NgocPham I tried `posts` 1st I got the error `prefetch_related` must be a tuple or a list I added a `,` then I got the error `posts is a invalid parameter to prefetch_related`

Answer (score 2):

As per [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related):

> Returns a QuerySet that will “follow” **foreign-key** relationships,
>   selecting additional related-object data when it executes its query.
>   This is a performance booster which results in a single more complex
>   query but means later use of **foreign-key** relationships won’t
>   require database queries.

Means `select_related` will work only for [OneToOne](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField) and [ForignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) relations.

In here, you are using [SelectRelatedMixin](https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces/blob/master/docs/other.rst#id23) and it has `select_related`. In that field there is *group* and *user*. That might be causing the problem. Instead use [PrefethRelatedMixin](https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces/blob/master/docs/other.rst#id4) like this:

```
class PostDetail(PrefetchRelatedMixin, DetailView):
    model = Post
    prefetch_related = ('user', 'group')
```

Comment: I know I changed it to `prefetch_related` but it still gives the  error

Comment: In your code I can see that you are using [SelectRelatedMixin](https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces/blob/master/docs/other.rst#id23) and it has `select_related`. In here there is *group* and *user*. That might be causing problem

Comment: So do you suggest I remove `SelectRelatedMixin ` and change `select_related` to `prefetch_related`

Comment: I suggest you to use [PrefethRelatedMixin](https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces/blob/master/docs/other.rst#id4)

Comment: @SamirTendulkar please see my updated answer. hope it helps

Comment: I have changed it still gives me the error see question. I believe its almost solved

Comment: Also the post.group is showing `groups.Group.None` in ORM and Django Admin group is blank

Comment: it should be `post.group.all()` or if you have a group then `group.posts.all()`

Comment: where do I add this

Comment: You are getting the error because you are passing empty slug. If you want to pass group slug then you need to iterate through the `object.group.all()` in template and pass the `group.slug`. It is really hard to pin point the error as you have shared a screenshot with partial error.

Comment: I am assuming you need do it like this: `{% for group in object.group.all %} {% url "single" group.slug %} {% endfor %}`